# Selenium webdriver opens firefox but doesn't fetch page through Selenium and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm starting work with selenium along NodeJS and set up a simple config file.

**test.config.js**

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
  By = webdriver.By,
  until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('firefox')
  .build();

driver.get('http://www.yahoo.com');
```

When I run `$ node test.config.js`

Selenium open **Firefox** but doesn't go to yahoo page. In chrome, all works fine.

Below my settings:

Firefox Quantum 63.0.3 64 bits.

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS 64 bits.

Geckodriver version 0.11.1

node version: 8.11.3

**Firefox open by selenium**

[image]
What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Geckodriver* version **0.11.1** is quite **ancient** and is incompatible with **Firefox Quantum v63.0.3**

### Solution

Download and install the compatible version of [*Geckodriver*](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) as per the chart the current released version being **Geckodriver v0.23.0**

---

### [*GeckoDriver*, *Selenium* and *Firefox Browser* compatibility chart](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html)

[image: supported_platforms_geckodriver]